# Building a multidimensional json object

Tags: php, json

I'm building tax calculator, and I have been able to build a JSON object for one key.  I need to extend it to have 3 more objects, but am have having trouble.

Currently, I can do net income doing this:

```
$a       = array();
$a_json      = array();
$a_json_row  = array();
$a_json_row2  = array();
$a_json_final      = array();


if ($queryIndexData) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($queryIndexData)) {
        $person      = $row['person'];
        $netincome = $row['NetIncome'];
        $statetax  = $row['StateTax'];
        $fedtax    = $row['FedTax'];
        $totaltax  = $row['TotalTax'];

        $a = array(
            'label' => $person,
            'value' => $netincome * 1,
        );
        array_push($a_json, $a);


     }
    $a_json_row2[key] = 'Net Income';
    $a_json_row2[values] = $a_json;
    array_push($a_json_final, $a_json_row2);

// jQuery wants JSON data
echo json_encode($a_json_final);
```

It's not very clean and  I hard coded the key.  How can I dynamically generate the key from my $netincome, $statetax, $fedtax, and $totaltax variable?

so my JSON looks like:

```
var tax_data = [
    {
        key: 'Net Income',
        values: [
                    {
                        "label" : "John Doe" ,
                        "value" : 1000000
                    } ,
                    {
                        "label" : "Jane Doe" ,
                        "value" : 1500000
                    } ,
                ]
            },
    {
        key: 'State and City Taxes',
        values: [
                    {
                        "label" : "John Doe" ,
                        "value" : 1000000 
                    } ,
                    {
                        "label" : "Jane Doe" ,
                        "value" : 1500000 
                    } ,
                ]
            },
    {
        key: 'Federal Taxes',
        values: [
                    {
                        "label" : "John Doe" ,
                        "value" : 1000000
                    } ,
                    {
                        "label" : "Jane Doe" ,
                        "value" : 1500000
                    } ,
                ]
            },
    {
        key: 'Total Due',
        values: [
                    {
                        "label" : "John Doe" ,
                        "value" : 1000000  
                    } ,
                    {
                        "label" : "Jane Doe" ,
                        "value" : 1500000 
                    } ,

                ]
            }
        ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work, though it's a rather strange way of arranging your data. Note that the construct `$array[] = 1` is identical to (and more common than) `array_push($array, 1)`. Also, [**do not** use `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

```
$keys = array(
    "NetIncome"=>"Net Income",
    "State Tax"=>"State and City Taxes",
    "FedTax"=>"Federal Taxes",
    "TotalTax"=>"Total Due"
);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($queryIndexData)) {
    foreach ($keys as $column=>$keys) {
        $a_json[$column][] = array(
            'label' => $row["person"],
            'value' => $row[$column] * 1,
        );
    }
}
foreach ($keys as $column=>$key) {
    $a_json_final[] = array(
        "key"=>$key,
        "values"=>$a_json[$column]
    );
}

// jQuery wants JSON data
echo json_encode($a_json_final);
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice and answer,  why do you say it is stored in weird arrangement?

Comment: I would just expect that storing information with the person as a key would be more useful. Depends on your application though.

Comment: Ah, ok.  I'm new.  I'm trying to see all the state taxes for a set of people.  Could you do that if a person was the key?

Comment: Well I would be just asking the database for it and saving all this mucking around with arrays. `SELECT person, NetIncome FROM tablename`. I'd also be using a PDO connection which would dump the result set directly into an array.